# Add together simple equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have three equations

$$
x = 20 \\
-x+a = 10 \\
y = 2
$$

Can I add these equations and get

$$
x-x+a+y = 20+10+2 \\
a+y = 32?
$$

If yes, what is the name of the rule applied?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this. I doubt that there is any name that is in general use. Its done so often in so many different contexts.